# Adjusting collision hitbox size with Pygame

Tags: pygame

So I coded a 2d sidescrolling platform, everything is fine except this:

[image: The sprite stands on platform with her sword]

As you can see, the sprite is standing at the platform when her feet is not in the platform anymore. I want to adjust the collision hitbox size so that when her feet is not on the platform, she falls to the ground.

Below is the code for sprite initiation:

```
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #Initiating the player (23 / 5)
    #because there is only one character right now, it will have no case for character selection (23 / 5)
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

         #width and height of character (23 / 5)
         width = 80
         height = 120

         #character sprite goes here (23 / 5)
         self.image = pygame.image.load("Malahayati.jpg").convert_alpha()
         self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(width,height))

         #hitbox (23 / 5)
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

         #character speed (23 / 5)
         self.vx = 0
         self.vy = 0

         #references to the list of sprite we bumped against (24 / 5)
         self.level = None

         #current state: 0 is idle, 1 is moving right, 2 is moving left, 3 is dashing
         self.status = 0

         #character status (24 / 5)
         self.rank = 1
         self.health = 220
         self.attack = 50
         self.defense = 20
         self.speed = 52.5
         self.exp = 0
         self.jumpspeed = 125
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to give your sprites a second Rect attribute, the scaled `hitbox` which will be used for the collision detection. You have to do that because the `self.rect.topleft` coordinates are used as the blit position and if you shrink the Rect, it will be smaller but only fill the upper left area of the image. (The darker area represents the scaled Rect and the brighter area the image.)

```
 ________
|░░░░░   |
|░░░░░   |
|░░░░░   |
|        |
|________|
```

So create the `hitbox` either by scaling the original Rect with the [`inflate`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) method or create a new one with the desired size. I also give my sprites a `pos` attribute (a `pygame.math.Vector2`) which represents the actual center position of the sprites. When the pos is updated in the `update` method, you have to assign it to the `center` of the rect and the hitbox as well in order to move them.

Then define a custom collision detection function which will be passed as the `collided` argument to [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) or `groupcollide`. In this function you can use the `colliderect` method of the `hitbox` Rect to check if it collides with the rect (or `hitbox`) of the other sprite.

In your case you also need to shift the hitbox because the weapon of the character is so large. You can do this by defining a vector (called `offset` here) which you have to add to the `self.hitbox` every update. When the character and its image are flipped, you also have to invert the `self.offset` vector.

Here's a minimal, complete example. The images are blue and gray (with the hitboxes centered at the blue area), the hitboxes red and the outer rects (`self.rect` for the blitting) are green. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to flip the player sprite.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
IMAGE = pg.Surface((70, 110))
IMAGE.fill((0, 80, 180))
pg.draw.rect(IMAGE, (160, 160, 160), (0, 0, 20, 110))


class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        # A deflated copy of the rect as the hitbox.
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-40, -20)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)  # Actual center position.
        self.offset = Vector2(10, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        # Add the offset to the pos to center the hitbox
        # at the blue part of the image.
        self.hitbox.center = self.pos + self.offset

    def flip(self):
        # Check which side the sprite is facing.
        if self.offset.x > 0:
            self.image = pg.transform.flip(IMAGE, True, False)
        else:
            self.image = IMAGE
        self.offset = -self.offset  # Invert the offset.
            

# This callback function is passed as the `collided`argument
# to pygame.sprite.spritecollide or groupcollide.
def collided(sprite, other):
    """Check if the hitboxes of the two sprites collide."""
    return sprite.hitbox.colliderect(other.hitbox)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Entity((300, 200), all_sprites)
    player.flip()
    enemies = pg.sprite.Group(
        Entity((100, 250), all_sprites),
        Entity((400, 300), all_sprites),
        )

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                player.pos = event.pos
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    player.flip()

        all_sprites.update()
        # Pass the custom collided callback function to spritecollide.
        collided_sprites = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemies, False, collided)
        for sp in collided_sprites:
            print('Collision', sp)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))

        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            # Draw rects and hitboxes.
            pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 230, 0), sprite.rect, 2)
            pg.draw.rect(screen, (250, 30, 0), sprite.hitbox, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Alternatively, you could give your sprite two offset vector attributes and add the current offset to the `rect.topleft` position when you blit the sprite. However, that means the sprite group's `draw` method can't be used anymore and you have to blit the sprites in a `for` loop. On the other hand, you wouldn't need the `hitbox` and the `collided` callback function anymore.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
IMAGE = pg.Surface((70, 110))
IMAGE.fill((0, 80, 180))
pg.draw.rect(IMAGE, (160, 160, 160), (0, 0, 20, 110))
IMAGE_FLIPPED = pg.transform.flip(IMAGE, True, False)


class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos).inflate(-40, -20)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)  # Actual center position.
        self.offset_right = Vector2(-30, -10)
        self.offset_left = Vector2(-10, -10)
        self.offset = self.offset_right

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def flip(self):
        # Check which side the sprite is facing.
        if self.offset.x <= -30:
            # Swap the image and the offset vector.
            self.image = IMAGE_FLIPPED
            self.offset = self.offset_left  
        else:
            self.image = IMAGE
            self.offset = self.offset_right


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Entity((300, 200), all_sprites)
    player.flip()
    enemies = pg.sprite.Group(
        Entity((100, 250), all_sprites),
        Entity((400, 300), all_sprites),
        )
    # Define blit as a local variable to increase the performance.
    blit = screen.blit

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                player.pos = event.pos
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    player.flip()

        all_sprites.update()
        collided_sprites = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemies, False)
        for sp in collided_sprites:
            print('Collision with id', id(sp))

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            # Add the current offset to the blit position.
            blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+sprite.offset)
            pg.draw.rect(screen, (250, 30, 0), sprite.rect, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: In short, I have to create another box that will be used as collision hitbox , that followed the character spriteholder box?

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to learn your code now, I will give an update later on
I need to break it down so I can use this method in my code

Answer (score 0):

The hitbox is set up in this line:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Documentation gives the following constructor: `Rect(left, top, width, height)`
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

So you need to change the above line to this (replacing `characterWidth` with the new narrower width, and `offset` to the width of the whitespace to the left of the character's feet):

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.image.get_rect().left + offset, self.image.get_rect().top, characterWidth, self.image.get_rect().height)
```

It looks like the whitespace is *almost* (but not exactly) half the width of the sprite, so here's a working example you can play around with until it looks right (change the two 40s, but ensure the two values always add up to 80):

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.image.get_rect().left + 40, self.image.get_rect().top, 40, self.image.get_rect().height)
```

Comment: It worked, but on the opposite side