# How do I reduce the size of a sprite hitbox?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making my own pygame game, but I want to reduce the size of the player's hitbox in order to make dodging bullets easier.

```
import math
import pygame
from src import util


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, group):
        super().__init__(group)
        self.weapon = None
        self.experience = 0
        self.animation = [pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_0_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_1_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_2_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_3_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_4_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_5_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_6_delay-0.05s.png")),
                          pygame.image.load(util.sprites("frame_7_delay-0.05s.png"))]
        self.frame = 0
        right_player_animation = self.animation[self.frame]
        self.image = right_player_animation
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-40, -20)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.facing = "right"
        self.speed = 5
        self.speed_modifier = 1
        self.kill_count = 0

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.direction.y = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.direction.y = 1
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            self.speed_modifier = 0.5
        else:
            self.speed_modifier = 1

    def set_position(self, pos):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def set_weapon(self, weapon):
        self.weapon = weapon

    def attack(self):
        if self.weapon:
            self.weapon.attack()
            pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound(util.sound("gun_fire.mp3")))

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.rect.center += self.direction * self.speed * self.speed_modifier
        self.frame += 1
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dx, dy = mouse_x - 640, mouse_y - 360
        look_direction = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx))
        if look_direction < 0:
            look_direction = 360 + look_direction
        if 270 > look_direction > 90:
            self.facing = 'left'
        else:
            self.facing = 'right'
        animation_index = (self.frame // 3) % len(self.animation)
        if self.facing == "right":
            self.image = self.animation[animation_index]
        else:
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.animation[animation_index], True, False)

        if self.weapon:
            self.weapon.direction = look_direction
            self.weapon.set_position(self.rect.center)
```

Comment: Doesn't the way you do it work?

Comment: This might be of use: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/159082/3770

Comment: btw: when you move player position `self.rect` then you have to also move its `hitbox` - pygame will NOT move it automatically.